# Target MovieClip from non-Document Class in Flash

Tags: flash, class, target, movieclip

is there any way to target a MovieClip from an external class that's NOT the Document Class?

Is it correct to have the Document Class as Main AND View?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a MovieClip from any class that is part of the project. If the MovieClip is manually placed on the stage, you just need to give it an instance name.

If you want to dynamically create an instance, make sure 'Export for Actionscript' is selected in the MovieClip's properties and use this in your (AS3) project:

Add second class to display list from the doc class:

```
var newClass:ClassName = new ClassName();
addChild(newClass);
```

Add MovieClip to display list in the second class:

```
var myClip:MovieClipName = new MovieClipName();
addChild(myClip);
```